# Write test-case in JEST-Enzyme for promise calling in constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, es6-promise, enzyme

I need to write the rendering test-case for a React class component which is having the promise which is getting called in constructor function.

**Constructor function of React class component** :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.getPaypalAuthUrl().then((result) => {
        this.setState({authUrl: result})
    });
}
```

**My Test case** :

```
test(testIDAndStatement.settings.TC086, async () => {
        const wrapper = await shallow(<Payment getPaypalAuthUrl={getPaypalAuthUrl}/>);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        instance.constructor();
        wrapper.setState({ connectedToPaypal: true });
        const paymentComponent = wrapper.find('.settings-payment__wrapper');
        expect(paymentComponent.length).toBe(1);
    });
```

Error getting :

> TypeError: this.props.getPaypalAuthUrl(...).then is not a function

**Solutions I have tried**: I have tried to write my test case with async-await and tried to get the instance of constructor like we get for the life cycle or normal methods.

Comment: Why are you manually invoking the constructor?  When the component is mounted via `shallow` the constructor will be called

Comment: Please post the fake `getPaypalAuthUrl ` that you're passing in the test.

Comment: @James I'have tried it on the basis of lifecycle methods

Comment: @KevinCollins it is giving me error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: @HarshalMahajan in your test you should define `getPaypalAuthUrl` as a fake or mock function and have it return a promise. That way you can control what's returned when the `<Payment>` component calls it. The testdouble.js library is good for this https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js/#tdwhenthenresolve-and-tdwhenthenreject

Comment: @KevinCollins Thanks for the suggestion, I have mocked the function with return the promise and it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether or not the side effects are done correctly in the constructor. 
Here is the unit test solution for your case:

`index.jsx`:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SomeCompoennt extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { authUrl: '' };
    this.props.getPaypalAuthUrl().then((result) => {
      this.setState({ authUrl: result });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <div>some component</div>;
  }
}

export default SomeCompoennt;
```

`index.spec.jsx`:

```js
import SomeCompoennt from './index';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('58877501', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mProps = {
      getPaypalAuthUrl: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('http://github.com'),
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<SomeCompoennt {...mProps}></SomeCompoennt>);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('some component');
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ authUrl: '' });
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve));
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual({ authUrl: 'http://github.com' });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58877501/index.spec.tsx (10.985s)
  58877501
    ✓ should pass (24ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.jsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.808s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58877501